# Remove "http://" and "https://" from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

am new to ruby
using regular expression .how can i remove `https` and `http` and `www` from a string

```
server= http://france24.miles.com
server= https://seloger.com
```

from these sites i want to remove all `http ,https and www`

```
france24.miles.com
seloger.com
```

i used following code but it is not woking for me

```
server = server.(/^https?\:\/\/(www.)?/,'')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
server = server.(/^https?\:\/\/(www.)?/,'')
```

This didn't work, because you aren't calling a method of the string `server`. Make sure you call the `sub` method:

```
server = server.sub(/^https?\:\/\/(www.)?/,'')
```

Example

```
> server = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
> server = server.sub(/^https?\:\/\/(www.)?/,'')
stackoverflow.com
```

As per the requirement if you want it to work with the illegal format `http:\\` as well, use the following regex:

```
server.sub(/https?\:(\\\\|\/\/)(www.)?/,'')
```

Comment: Updated answer to make it work with https:\\ as well

Comment: @Psl, ``http:\\`` is simply wrong. You are doing your users a disservice if you accept such a URL.

Answer (score 8):

Std-lib URI is dedicated for such kind of work. Using this would be simpler and may be more reliable

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.ruby-lang.org/")

uri.host
=> "www.ruby-lang.org"

uri.host.sub(/\Awww\./, '')
=> "ruby-lang.org"
```

Comment: i used `uri = URI.parse(server)  
 uri.host 
    content = Net::HTTP.get(uri.host.gsub('\Awww\.', ''), '/status')` but getting `bad URI(is not URI?): http:\\ingen.twosmiles.com`

Comment: @Psi, `Net::HTTP.get` expect a full url with protocol http or https etc. If this is your usage, you should not remove 'http'

Comment: This doesn't appear to work - I still get the full `www.ruby-lang.org` string back unless I do `uri.host.sub(/\Awww\./, '')`

Answer (score 6):

See the [`String#sub(...)` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-sub).

Also, consider using the [`%r{...}` literal notation for Regexp objects](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) so that forward-slashes (`/`) are easier to recognize:

```ruby
def trim_url(str)
  str.sub %r{^https?:(//|\\\\)(www\.)?}i, ''
end

trim_url 'https://www.foo.com' # => "foo.com"
trim_url 'http://www.foo.com'  # => "foo.com"
trim_url 'http://foo.com'      # => "foo.com"
trim_url 'http://foo.com'      # => "foo.com"
```

Here is what each part of the regular expression means:

```
%r{^https?:(//|\\\\)(www\.)?}
#  │├──┘├┘│├───────┘ ├─┘├┘ └── everything in the group (...), or nothing.
#  ││   │ ││         │  └── the period character "."
#  ││   │ ││         └── the letters "www".
#  ││   │ │└── the characters "//" or "\\".
#  ││   │ └── the colon character ":".
#  ││   └── the letter "s", or nothing.
#  │└── the letters "http".
#  └── the beginning of the line.
```

Comment: Very nice, how do you generate lines to description like that?

Comment: @MartinKonecny: thanks, I just copy/paste [UTF-8 box-drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

Answer (score 2):

```
def strip_url(url)
    return url.to_s.sub!(/https?(\:)?(\/)?(\/)?(www\.)?/, '') if url.include?("http")
    url.to_s.sub!(/(www\.)?/,'') if url.include?("www")
  end
```

This will change in place the provided url, stripped of any leading http(s) or www. It covers the following formats:

- `http://www.example.com`
- `http:/www.example.com`
- `http:www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`
- `https:/www.example.com`
- `https:www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `http:/example.com`
- `http:example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `https:/example.com`
- `https:example.com`
- `www.example.com`
- `example.com`

You'll end up with `example.com` using this method.

Answer (score 1):

With this regex: `server\s*=\s*\Khttps?://(?:www\.)?`

**In Ruby 2.0+**

```
result = subject.gsub(/server\s*=\s*\Khttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/, '')
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/aU7tA0), see the replacements at the bottom.

Hang tight for explanation. :)

**Explanation**

- `server\s*=\s*` matches `server=` with optional spaces, to make sure we are looking at the right strings
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match
- `https?` matches `http` with an optional `s`
- `://` matches these literal characters
- `(?:www\.)?` matches an optional `www.`
- we replace the match with an empty string

**Earlier Versions of Ruby**

`\K` is only supported from Ruby 2.0+. Earlier versions have to use a lookbehind:

```
result = subject.gsub(/(?:(?<=server=)|(?<=server= ))https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/, '')
```

Comment: FYI, added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: but in my code it is not working..and what is subject??

Comment: What version of Ruby?

Comment: i have this string http:\\integration.twosmiles.com ` server = ARGV[0]

puts server
result = server.gsub(/server\s*=\s*\Khttps?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/, '')
puts result`

Comment: \K is only supported from Ruby 2.0+. Added a second option for earlier versions. :)

Comment: @Psl is that server is a variable name? Why didn't you mention this? @zx81 assumes `server=` as a part of the input string even me also.