# How can I remove https and http from ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to remove the "https" and the "http" from a url from my form in order to show the image later, I got the form where i'm including title and url like this:

Form:

```
<%= form_for( @article, :html => { class: "form-test", role: "form"}) do |f| %>      
    <%= f.label :Titulo %>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>

    <%= f.label :Imagen%>
    <%= f.text_field :img%>

     <%= f.submit "Post"%>
<% end %>
```

View:

```
<div class="header">
    <%= image_tag("https://#{@article.img}") %>
    <%= @article.title%>
</div>
```

I'am looking for option how should I remove the https I will really appreciate if you can tell me.

Comment: Do you mean, do you want to disable https in your app?

Comment: Why not use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) and upgrade your site to HTTPS instead of presuming the other site will work in HTTP mode, which it may not due to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). As an example, the entire `.app` gTLD *requires* HTTPS, it is not optional.

Comment: I just want to remove the http and https from img

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24378324/10068463

Comment: do you want to remove the them in the database or the view only?

Comment: only in the view it is for a slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to use ruby `URI` so long as your string only contains a valid url.  See answer by @CAmador from which this answer evolved.  Either solution can be wrapped in a helper and used in the view.

```
def url_no_scheme(url)
  url = "https://foobar.com"
  uri = URI(url)
  uri.hostname + uri.path
end

url_no_scheme('https://foobar.com')
=>"foobar.com"    
url_no_scheme('http://foobar.com')
=>"foobar.com"
```

In the view you can call the helper

```
<%= image_tag(url_without_scheme @article.img) %>
```

This might be helpful for someone looking to do this outside of rails and may have a string with multiple URLs which can be removed with a regular expression:

```
str = "https://foobar.com or http://foobar.com"
str.gsub(/https:\/\/|http:\/\//, "")
=> "foobar.com or foobar.com"
```

Comment: I think `URL` should be `URI` in this solution:

`uri = URI(url)`

Comment: @ShawnAukstak thanks, updated.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby's [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) maybe?

```rb
~ ᐅ irb                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [ruby-2.5.3] 
2.5.3 :001 > uri = URI('https://my.domain.com/my_image.png')
 => #<URI::HTTPS https://my.domain.com/my_image.png> 
2.5.3 :002 > [uri.hostname, uri.path].join
 => "my.domain.com/my_image.png"
```

You can define a helper for that:

```rb
def url_without_scheme(url)
  uri = URI(url)
  uri.hostname + uri.path
end
```

View:

```rb
<div class="header">
  <%= image_tag(url_without_scheme @article.img) %>
  <%= @article.title%>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, suggest a helper and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: What’s the benchmark look like if you stop making a needless array and just do the string interpolation of the two pieces yourself? Arrays are slow.

Comment: Updated answer removing needless array. Ty, @Nate ;-)

Comment: benchmark with updated method, same result. But what if the source has already removed http ? then it will raise where regex won't.

Comment: Who cares if the regex is faster when you are not doing it 10000 times in a row? Also URI will not raise if you don't have a scheme. `URI('my.domain.com/my_image.png')` just gives you a `URI::Generic`.