# How to access Ruby object inside string in a erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a `erb` file where in I want to access ruby object and attach it inside a string dynamically. Here is the code snippet I have. Ideally, I want to access the ruby object and then parse it. But, it dosent work as expected. Below, `@ruby_object` is some kind of URL based on different env.

```
 <div>
       Visit this <a href="<%="google.com"%>">@ruby_object.sub('http', '')}"</a>.
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually this did the trick for me.

```
 <div>
       Visit this <a href="<%="google.com"%>"><%=@ruby_object.dup.sub!(/https?(\:)?(\/)?(\/)?/, '') %></a>`.
 </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855279/308731 This might or might not be simpler depending on your tastes.